# error C2679: binary '<<':no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string'

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a simple linked list of books and I am trying to print the contents of the linked list using this method

```
void List::display()const{

    Node *newNode = head;

    while (newNode != NULL){
        cout << "ID: " << newNode->book.getId() << " Name: " << newNode->book.getName()<< endl;
        newNode = newNode->next;
    }
}
```

My `Book` class has the following implementations:

```
int Book::getId(){
    return id;
}

string Book::getName(){
    return name;
}
```

The `Book.h` has the following declarations:

```
class Book{
    friend class Node;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Book &book);
public:
    Book();
    int getId();
    string getName();

private:
    int id;
    string name;
};
```

Getting it to print the `ID` of the book is fine:

```
cout << "ID: " << newNode->book.getId()
```

Its the second part which does not work:

```
cout<<" Name: " << newNode->book.getName()<< endl;
```

I've tried this before in a couple of different linked lists and it works fine, but I cant figure out what's wrong here,

the error is:

> Error 1   error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a
>   right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)

Comment: `#include <string>` is missing.

Comment: Can you pleaser try and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably forgot:

```
#include <string>
```

Comment: @JohnQ321 do not feel alone! :)